# how to re install ubuntu on the fedora partition

Tags: re-installation

I have a windows 7 partition of 200 GB.

I have currently installed Fedora 16 on the remaining 30 GB partition and now want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on the 30 GB partition.

Help me how to do so. Also write to me detailed installation process of Ubuntu 12.04.

Please provide pictures or videos if possible for the detailed installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Boot from Ubuntu disk
- Choose something else for selection screen.
- Format the 30GB partition that fedora was on.
- Choose that partition for Ubuntu install.
- Enjoy your new Ubuntu Install

Bill

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from Ubuntu install disk.
2. When reaching the disk partitioning screen, choose "Something else", then delete the Fedora's partition.
3. Choose to install Ubuntu on the free space.